# how to convert guest to customer and send email to reset password in magento 2

Tags: orders, customer-account, magento2.2.6

How to convert guest to customer using order id and how to send them password reset email in magento 2.

Please provide me a solution to send convert guest to customer

Comment: You can this plugin for "Guest To Customer" :  https://github.com/magepal/magento2-guest-to-customer

Answer (score 0):

To Send Email

**In observer:(evevnt:checkout_onepage_controller_success_action)**

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class SendMailOnOrderSuccess implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $orderModel;
    protected $orderSender;
    protected $checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(OrderFactory $orderModel, OrderSender $orderSender, CheckoutSession $checkoutSession)
    {
        $this->orderModel = $orderModel;
        $this->orderSender = $orderSender;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        //On Order Success Event, Get Order Id and Send Order Confirmation Email
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        if (count($orderIds)) {
            $this->checkoutSession->setForceOrderMailSentOnSuccess(true);
            $order = $this->orderModel->create()->load($orderIds[0]);
            $this->orderSender->send($order, true);
        }
    }
```